# Conditional colouring with kableExtra() fails with NAs in column

Tags: r, r-markdown, kableextra

I use the kableExtra()-package for conditional formatting of tables in an PDF-output Rmarkdown report. All works pretty much fine, but fails if in one column is a NA present.

The original report contains columns with percentage agreement on a specific variable (e.g. 21% (but % not in the cell)) , however it will show NA if the value is based on less than 10 answers for protection of subjects answers, therefore I will have potential NAs in the table.

Here is a small reprex for a case when it works (no NA):

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
# load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(kableExtra)


# example when no NA are resent
df1 <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl, disp)
df1 <- head(df1, 10)
# kable
df1 %>%
  mutate(cyl = cell_spec(cyl, color = if_else(cyl == 8, "teal",
                                              if_else(cyl == 6, "orange", 
                                                      if_else(is.na(cyl), "black", "red"))))) %>%
    kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "")

```
````

here is the other one, when NAs are present:

````
```{r, eval=T}
# example when NA is present
df2 <- mtcars %>% select(mpg, cyl, disp)
df2 <- head(df2, 10)
df2$cyl[df2$cyl == 4] <- NA

# kable
df2 %>%
  mutate(cyl = cell_spec(cyl, color = if_else(cyl == 8, "teal",
                                              if_else(cyl == 6, "orange", "red")))) %>%
    kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "")


```
````

the error running the chunk is :

```
Error in if (substr(color, 1, 1) != "#") { : missing value where 
TRUE/FALSE needed
```

the error when knitting is:

[image]

I also tried adding a third if_else() which evaluates to is.na() - the errors stay the same:

```
# kable
df2 %>%
  mutate(cyl = cell_spec(cyl, color = if_else(cyl == 8, "teal",
                                              if_else(cyl == 6, "orange", 
                                                      if_else(is.na(cyl), "black","red"))))) %>%
    kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "")
```

My session.info:

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] naniar_0.4.1       shurp2018_0.0.9000 kableExtra_1.0.1   forcats_0.3.0      stringr_1.3.1      dplyr_0.8.0        purrr_0.3.0       
 [8] readr_1.3.1        tidyr_0.8.2        tibble_2.0.99.9000 ggplot2_3.1.0      tidyverse_1.2.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have two problems:

First, I think that by default, no color value is set. Yet it is also not overwritten when for some cells `color = NA`. So you could solve it by setting `color = NULL` (any other color would be concatenated with the ones assigned in the next step, which causes trouble).So this works somewhat for me:

````
```{r}
# kable
df2 %>%
  mutate(cyl = cell_spec(cyl, color = NULL)) %>% 
  mutate(cyl = cell_spec(cyl, color = if_else(cyl == 8, "teal",
                                              if_else(cyl == 6, "orange", "red")))) %>%
    kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "")
```
````

The problem is that the color of `NA` is red now instead of black.

The second problem is that your `ifelse` evaluations do not work correctly

You can also check what happens in your `ifelse` function separately to get a better understanding of this problem:

```
> with(df2,  if_else(cyl == 8, "teal",
+                    if_else(cyl == 6, "orange", 
+                            if_else(is.na(cyl), "black","red"))))
 [1] "orange" "orange" NA       "orange" "teal"   "orange" "teal"   NA       NA       "orange"
```

But you can make it work by evaluating `is.na(cyl)` first instead of last:

```
df2 %>%
  mutate(cyl = cell_spec(cyl, color = if_else(is.na(cyl), "black", 
                                              if_else(cyl == 8, "teal",
                                                      if_else(cyl == 6, "orange", "red"))))) %>%
  kable("latex", escape = F, booktabs = TRUE, linesep = "")
```

Comment: great, the 2nd option with putting ```is.na(cyl)``` first works - now I have a further problem: I set ```options(knitr.kable.NA = '-')``` in the very beginning of my document, but now I get "NA" instead - I assume its because kable does not evaluate the \textcolor{"black"}{NA} as "NA" but as text...?

Comment: Hmm might be. I know that `knitr` also supports changing the resulting latex file by: `knit_hooks$set(document = function(x) {
                 gsub('\textcolor{"black"}{NA} ', '\textcolor{"black"}{-}', x, fixed = TRUE)
               })`. Maybe that would help.

Comment: No hooks needed. Just pipe into `gsub("NA", "-", .)`. The reason is that `cell_spec` obviously adds latex code inside the cell and therefore it is not `NA` anymore and `kable` does not recognize it.

Comment: for the sake of completeness: 
I tried @JBGruber 's hook - but I could not get it to work, but Martin Schmelzer ' s code at the end of kable() worked - thanks

Comment: Yes, I didn't test the hook. In a different document of mine it works but maybe `document` isn't the right hook in this case? Anyway, if the other suggestion works, that's great.